# Android Does not stay connected to ESP8266 in Soft Ap mode

Tags: android, iot, esp8266

So basically I'm creating a Wireless Weight Scale using a esp. I have built a android app that pulls the data from esp and displays and logs into a local database.
Problem I'm facing is that the wifi does not stay connected in my android device as it does not have access to the internet.

I have tried using multiple devices from various manufactures. In some there is a way to turn of "WiFi Assitant" or "Smart WiFi" but even with those turned off, It automatically switches to a network with active internet access or mobile data.
I have tried to forcefully connect to the esp ssid from inside my app but as most of the apis are depreceated on android 10 onwards, that does'nt work either.
Is there anything that can be done in this matter or do I have to switch to bluetooth.

Comment: Switch off mobile connection and forget all other wifi stations.

Comment: Tried that but does not work.

Comment: Then what happens instead?

Comment: Wifi disconnects and reconnects, this continues until it gets internet access from another wifi network or mobile data.

Comment: Well that is impossible when mobile data is switched off and all wifi stations forgotten. So you did not try.